# PySpark: do I need to re-cache a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe:

```
rdd = sc.textFile(file)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.cache()
```

and I add a column

`df = df.withColumn('c1', lit(0))`

I want to use `df` repeatedly. So do I need to re-`cache()` the dataframe, or does Spark automatically do it for me?

Answer (score 9):

you will have to re-cache the dataframe again everytime you manipulate/change the dataframe. However the entire dataframe doesn't have to be recomputed.

```
df = df.withColumn('c1', lit(0))
```

In the above statement a new dataframe is created and reassigned to variable `df`. But this time only the new column is computed and the rest is retrieved from the cache.